# Cannot install printer driver epson l210

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I want to install printer driver in ubuntu 13.10. but when I tried to install it, I got an error message like this :

[image]

Please help me...Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If you installed drivers from Epson site, they require some other packages to be installed too. But the problem is that 13.10 is not supported any more, and you won't get these packages from repository.

There is a way to connect "old-releases" repository, but I suggest upgrading the system to 14.04.

This will be closed as off topic anyway, since the question is about unsupported release.

Comment: so I should upgrade my system to 14.04.  Thank you for your help.